# CLI Client(SnowSQL) Not available for Download in Help —> Downloads

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql, snowflake-task

Where is the CLI Client(snowSQL) option to download SnowSQL CLI in help—>Download in Snowflake WebUI? Screen Shot attached

[Screen Shot Help —> Downloads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gaDF.png)

Comment: nod it seems to be "missing" from my instance also.

Comment: Same here. Snowflake team is working on a resolution. Meanwhile, the SnowSQL client can be downloaded from this link: https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: Isn't that message telling you to download the driver from the Maven Repository though? If you follow that link, it will take you to all the available versions of the JDBC driver and associated files.

Comment: You can refer to below documentation link for Snowsql installation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#installing-snowsql

Comment: I agree and I know we can download even from AWS/Azure end-points but downloading from help—>downloads was comparatively simple than downloading from maven repository..Thank you….

Comment: According to the release email that just went out https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements.html#recommended-versions notes that snowsql should be downloaded from https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql/bootstrap/index.html which the localtion Clement linked to.